# Angular 2 - Set bootstrap class depend of string value

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I have a doubt and I don't know how to solve.I bring some data from server and show it on a table. One of these fields it's a string with values like 'OK', 'ERROR' or 'CANCEL'. It possible to assign some bootstrap classes depending of value? For example bg-succes if it 'OK' or bg-danger if 'CANCEL'.

Example:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead class="thead-inverse">
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center"><strong>Date 1/ Date 2</strong></th>
            <th class="text-center"><strong>Status</strong></th>
            <th class="text-center"><strong>Date 3</strong></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of items">
            <td class="text-center">  
              <tr class="text-center"> {{item.Date1}} </tr>
              <tr class="text-center"> {{item.Date2}} </tr>
            </td>
             <td class="text-center">
                <tr>Status</tr>
                <tr class="bg-success"> {{item.Status}}</tr>//Want to assign here the class                  
            </td>
            <td class="text-center"> {{item.Date3}} </td>            
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks by the way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve the same using `ngClass` directive.

```
<tr [ngClass]="getStatusClass(item.Status)"> {{item.Status}}</tr>
```

**Code**

```
getStatusClass(status: string){
   let statuses = {"OK": "bg-success", "ERROR": "bg-danger", "CANCEL": "bg-warning"}
   return statuses[status] || 'bg-default';
}
```

Comment: Be careful though, Angular is case sensitive. your keys should be OK, ERROR and CANCEL, not ok, error and cancel.

Comment: That works! But just for the first element of the array. The others don't take any class :/

Comment: @trichetriche that not about Angular, here in this case dictionary keys are case sensitive :p Though I updated list, Thanks for heads up..

Comment: @Aw3same check updated answer... I added fallback class as well that will be `bg-default`

Comment: Still not work, only work with 'OK', but not with 'ERROR' and 'CANCEL'

Comment: Fixed, i'm stupid. I was assigning the wrong classes and that's why don't work. -.- Very gratefull men!

Comment: @Aw3same np, that happens. Glad that I helped you :)